# as.Date keeps returning NA - Mont-Year format

Tags: r

I imported csv data saved from excel and I am using a Mac if that matters.

To simplify things, I have been working with one particular entry from my data "Jan-12". This is of type character and in the form Month-Year.

This is what I have tried:

```
as.Date("Jan-12", format = "%b-%y")
```

I keep getting `NA`. I have browsed through other answers but haven't been able to figure out whats happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as.Date()` help page says:

> If the date string does not specify the date completely, the returned
> answer may be system-specific.

If you really need to use `as.Date()` you can append some fixed day (say 1st) to date and convert

```
mydate <- "Jan-12"
as.Date(paste0("01-", mydate), format= "%d-%b-%y")
"2012-01-01"
```

Or you can use `lubridate::fast_strptime()`:

```
library(lubridate)
fast_strptime("Jan-12", "%b-%y")
"2012-01-01 UTC"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `zoo`, then you can use `as.Date`.

```
library(zoo)

as.Date(as.yearmon("Jan-12", "%b-%y"))

# [1] "2012-01-01"
```